# Order of afterSave in CakePHP 3.x models and plugin models?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

We have a CakePHP 3.x app that uses plugins.  One plugin is a Customer list.

Another plugin is Complaints.

The main app has forms.  When the main form is entered, or a new Customer is added, we want the Complaints plugin to collect the information into it's own tables: complaints_main_form, complaints_customers, complaints_customer_permissions. So then, when the user creates a new complaint in the Complaints plugin, the complaint form can autocomplete info from the main form and Customer list plugins.  Also the Complaints plugin also has a permission system based on Customer type (from the Customer list plugin), and what action they can do in the Complaints system.

So my idea was to have a behaviour provided by the Complaints plugin, that would apply to the main app model.  This would then oversee the saves made to Customer plugin models, the main app forms, and then can appropriately fill its own tables.

```
[  Main App      [ Complaints.behaviour]        ]
[ Customer List ][ other plugins...][Complaints ]
```

Customer List is an independent plugin, used in different apps, so I don't want to touch that.

So would this work? Can a Comlpaints.behaviour in the main app model, detect afterSave of the plugin models? Is the afterSave in the app model called last, so by that time all the plugins have done their saves? Or is there another way to update one plugin based on changes in another?

Answer (score 1):

> So would this work? Can a Comlpaints.behaviour in the main app model, detect afterSave of the plugin models? Is the afterSave in the app model called last, soby that time all the plugins have done their saves? Or is there another way to update one plugin based on changes in another?

Yes, all of that is possible. Use events and [set a priority](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html#establishing-priorities) if you want to control the order. Check the subject of an event, if the subject is an instance of the plugins table object you know something happened there for the given event.

https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/events.html

Comment: Wow, so fast! Cheers.  I did check that, but wouldn't that mean the Customer plugin would need to be modified - which is what I am trying to avoid? And can all this code only be added to the Complaints .behaviour - so it's decoupled from the main app as well?